# Unable to retrieve data from Firebase unless user is signed in

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from Firebase but it won't retrieve anything unless I am signed in first. I've already tried editing my database's rules and setting the values to true.

Here are the Rules

```
{
"rules": { 
".read": true, 
".write": true
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) Show your code. 2) Show Your Code 3) show your rules. Once 1, 2 and 3 are completed, we can try to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Firebase console, you can click on Database --> Rules (Tab)

In there you can specify whether or not you need to be authenticated in order to retrieve your data.

```
"rules": {
   ".read": "auth == null",
   ".write": "auth == null"
}
```

I would only leave it this way for testing. It's pretty easy to setup the simple anonymous Auth through Firebase :) Best of luck!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind choosing this as the accepted answer I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In case if you don't want any security you can use the below rules

"rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true"
}